# Comparison of coefficients in fixed effects vs. non fixed-effects regressions

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, effects

I recently came across a [paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.2014.2103) that runs pairs of regressions, in which one regression includes unit fixed effects and the other regression  does not include unit fixed effects. The paper then compares the coefficient of interest of the fixed effects (FE) regression with the corresponding  coefficient  if the no fixed effects (no FE) regression. The goal of this procedure  to assess the degree to which fixed unit characteristics account for variation in the dependent variable.

However, I could not find a useful econometric reference that describes this procedure in detail. In fact, I wondered

1. Whether comparing coefficients of FE vs. non-FE models is an established procedure in applied econometrics
2. Whether comparing FE coefficients non-FE coefficients is appropriate.

The paper is the following (see chapter 5.4 for a description of the procedure):

- Pierce, Lamar, Daniel C. Snow, and Andrew McAfee. "Cleaning house: The impact of information technology monitoring on employee theft and productivity." Management Science 61.10 (2015): 2299-2319.